# How can I improve this rustic way to insert info in mySQL with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to know better ways to improve or optimize this rustic way of adding contents to my mySQL database with PHP only if the variables are not empty.
Thanks.

```
    <?php
      $fields = "value_1, value_2, value_3, value_4";
      $contents = "'$value1','$value2', '$value3', '$value4'";
      if(!empty($value5)){
        $fields .= ", value_5";
        $contents .= ", '$value5'";
      }
      if(!empty($value6)){
        $fields .= ", value_6";
        $contents .= ", '$value6'";
      }
      $add =    "INSERT INTO love_table " . "(" . $fields . ")" . "VALUES (" . $contents . ")";
    ?>
```

Comment: Better to use this https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php. It will also prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Yes sql injection comes here.

Answer (score 3):

You can refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp) for more details on Insert Data Into MySQL Using MySQLi.

```
//since the values in columns value5 and value6 can be NULL
$value5 = NULL
$value6 = NULL

//or if you want to set it to ""
$value5 = ""
$value6 = "" 

// Create connection
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

/* Prepare an insert statement */
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO love_table (value_1, value_2, value_3, value_4, value_5, value_6) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($insert_query);

/* Bind the parameters */
$stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $value1, $value2, $value3, $value4, $value5, $value6);

/* Execute the statement */
$stmt->execute();

/* close statement */
$stmt->close();

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

and why we should use bind parameters instead of directly using the values in the query (https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/bind-parameters)

Comment: Please keep in mind that this could still be vulnerable to SQL injection, because you didn't specify connection charset.

Comment: I 've really learned a lot with this... but I still have a problem that I cant resolve, I would like to pass a 7 value wich would be uuid() to generate an uuid, but I m getting errors because I think that is not a string, so I cant simply add an s and the value at the end... could please anyone help me with this?

Comment: yes, you can. If you can elaborate the problem with the error it would be helpful to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Plan A:  Leave the NULLs in the list, and have the columns 'default' the the value you want.

Plan B:  Change the NULLs on the fly  `..., (isset($val5) ? $val5 : 'N/A') , ...`

Plan C:  Like B, but in SQL, with `COALESCE(?, 'N/A')`.